WMS to WMS in QGIS
I would like to carry out evaluations of ecological measures at hydroelectric power plants for my master's thesis.
WMS and WFS access is available to me here, and this one is particularly important: https://rips-metadaten.lubw.de/trefferanzeige?docuuid=2d45854f-4d12-40ef-8526-9372160dc243&q=regel&rstart=0&currentSelectorPage=1&f= .
Now I can evaluate the WFS maps, but I should also do this with the WMS data and it would be far too time-consuming to do it by hand.
Is it possible to convert a WMS into a WFS file or to export data from the WMS layer?
I'm using QGIS.

WMS are image not data so you can't convert it to WFS and exporting will still give you an image. It seem that the data you reference are from some public German entity (I don't speak German) If that is the case they probably offer some way to download the data or provide some contact info where you can request it

Save the WMS frame by frame to raster data, merge that data, then vectorize it and complain about the shitty quality of the vector dataset. So no, not really possible.

If there is no corresponding WFS layer here https://rips-gdi.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/arcgis/rest/services/wfs then you are out of luck.

Request a 1 by 1 image and then to a GetFeatureInfo request, for the data underlying the image; might work, though probably not
